# Changing file permission in Android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am working on a project where I have an app that `unzip` a file which contains `.doc/.pdf` file.  I want to extract the zip file and want to get the `.doc/.pdf` file and set its permission to `Readable/ReadWrite`.

And now want to open the file with the proper app say for `MS-Word` or `PDF` viewer with the permission set for the files.  How can I do this ?any hint or idea?

Note : I want to use my app to extract the file and open it using the third party app with the set permission on the file.

---

As we can set the permission of a file in our application.The only problem is with opening the file in Third party apps.  Can I use Inter process communication mechanism in android to achieve this task so that we can have process to process communication between tow apps?

Provide me your suggestions on that.

Comment: Because of sandboxing (e.g. your app has only access to it's own files) the file must be "given" to the other app. There might be a way to do it using permissions, but that's the wrong way to go. I do not know how though, hence this comment (not an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unzip a file on **External Storage** then by default it has **All Permission** (The Permission which your External Storage has).

And if you are extracting within your application storage then its **Private** to your Application only (No third party application can easily access it). In this case use permission `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` .

Comment: The answer about external storage is good. But you should not use MODE_WORLD_READABLE inside your apps private files. Rather use the mechanism to give the file to the other app after extracting it.

Comment: @kw4nta - As Third party can access user app's files, The file has to permission `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`. And its only for those files. Not for entire application's Files.

Comment: Thanx for  the reply ,but i don;'t want to make the permission MODE_WORLD_READABLE , As it would be accessable to all.Is there any way i can change the file permission for the specific viewer.so that no other app can use the file .Or i can do somthing like sending signal to OS to make that file permission read or read write both.

Comment: For this type of requirement I don't think Android has any mechanism for permission to specific Application only..

Comment: @user370305 i even don't want it to be extracted in the External Storage.

Comment: @user370305,kW4nta - Such requirement/app has been implemented in the windows phone .Do u know what/how they might have done.